# How to duplicate a node and its children in Karate

Tags: api, testing, cucumber, karate

Hi I was trying to replace a node in the second level of the structure, eg the "two" node below (I want to duplicate this node and its children)

```
<root>
   <first>1</first>
   <second>
      <one>1</one>
      <two>
         <a>a</a>
         <b>b</b>
         <c>c</c>
      </two>
      <three>c</three>
   </second>
   <third>3</third>
</root>
```

So that it ends up looking like this:

```
<root>
   <first>1</first>
   <second>
      <one>1</one>
      <two>
         <a>a</a>
         <b>b</b>
         <c>c</c>
      </two>
      <two>
         <a>a</a>
         <b>b</b>
         <c>c</c>
      </two>
      <three>c</three>
   </second>
   <third>3</third>
</root>
```

Is this possible to do in Karate?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally I don't recommend tests that are "too clever" - each `Scenario` should be focused on one "static" payload - and you will thank yourself later when you try to read your tests.

Also make sure you look at this set of examples for "templating" ideas: [`xml.feature`](https://github.com/intuit/karate/blob/master/karate-junit4/src/test/java/com/intuit/karate/junit4/xml/xml.feature)

But anyway, here you go:

```
* def root =
"""
<root>
   <first>1</first>
   <second>
      <one>1</one>
      <two>
         <a>a</a>
         <b>b</b>
         <c>c</c>
      </two>
      <three>c</three>
   </second>
   <third>3</third>
</root>
"""
* xmlstring two = $root/root/second/two
* replace root.<three>c</three> = two + '<three>c</three>'
* xml root = root
* print root
```

Comment: Hi @Peter Thomas, thanks for answering, the structure of my request is relatively complicated so that's why I was trying to simplify the code. Just one more question, what if the 'three' node haves multiple child nodes included,like a tens of child nodes? Do I need to type out all of the child nodes when I'm replacing?

Comment: @Jackson depends.I have to admit that XML has limitations and I doubt that you can do this better in any other framework. I suggested alternate options. And I really think your approach to testing and test data is not ideal.